# A Basic Nested Drawer with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've spent a lot of time searching this board and google in general looking for a basic understanding on nesting the Drawer component in react.

I am trying to figure out how to have a sub-drawer in my drawer menu.

If I open my drawer menu, lets say it contains the items 'Home', 'Menu', and 'Help' - if I click on 'Menu' i do not want the default behavior of routing to the component 'Menu' screen. I would like another drawer that contains another list of items to replace that main drawer view. I can override the default behavior of the Drawer with a custom Drawer, but I can not figure out how to nest a Drawer.
If a visual helps, this repo has a gif of **exactly** what I want to achieve:
https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/native-kitchensink.

I have no code to share because it's little more than what is in the docs under 'Nesting Navigators'. I feel what I am trying to achieve is super basic, yet, there must be something I am missing. I've come across @react-nested-nav, but looks like it is no longer maintained and broken, so the examples i've come across online that use it, are of no help; I could not get it to work, and it requires an older version of react. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/native-kitchensink link is not using nested drawer, you can achieve it by defining and manage state clicked on menus and according to state you can display data according to you and on back just false the state you backed on drawer screen, hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks Alok for the info. I may not have cleaned up my env when i pulled down that repo to try it out, and my local react-nested-nav may have produced a false conflict. I will try with a clean env and go through the repo tonight again with the understanding that a nested drawer isnt being used